# SQL Injection - Compound statement?

Tags: sql, code-injection

Is it possible to SQL inject a single query that ends with `DESC` or `ASC` where those values or pulled from a variable?

```
SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values] ORDER BY low asc
```

Attempts to add a semicolon and a new statement will not work as the statement is loaded directly into a record set.

We have tried semi colon new statement
and
union
etc.

Is there any way to join a dataset into the first one without nesting as the first one isn't nested?

Edit:
The semicolon new command won't work as it all comes back as a record set.  It just throws all sorts of errors with a new command.  It is being fixed currently.  Just trying to show upper management that these things are not good practice.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what SQL Injection is.  Altering the returned data set is only one of the bad things that can be done with it (and probably the most benign at that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Why don't you validate the untrusted(!) input string?

```
Assert.IsTrue(str == "asc" || str == "desc");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, or course you can inject there.  Try it like this

```
SELECT * FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values] ORDER BY low asc; DROP TABLE Users;
```